# Android: creating a dialog

Tags: android

I think I followed [the Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) quite closely here. I have a `ListActivity` which calls a `showDialog(DIALOG_EXPORT);` at some point. My `onCreateDialog()` creates a dialog, sets an xml view and then tries to do something with the elements of that dialog, but directly after `findViewById()` everything is `null`. Why?

here the code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id){
    case DIALOG_EXPORT:
        final Dialog dial = new Dialog(this);
        dial.setContentView(R.layout.export_dialog);
        dial.setTitle(R.string.dialog_export_title);
        EditText eFile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_dialog_export);
        Button bOkay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_export_okay);
        Button bCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_export_cancel);
        <here all View elements are empty>
        ...
        return dial;

    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It all looks valid. Please paste the layout XML, just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `dial.findViewById()` instead of just `findViewById()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to inflate the view. You need to do something like this:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.yourview, null);
    Button positive = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_positive);
    Button negative = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_negative);

    positive.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeDialog(0);
        }
    });

    negative.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeDialog(0);
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    dialog.setView(view);

    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inflate the layout of the dialog per the tutorial.  Have another look at it.  It's in there.  Without inflating the layout, those other views will come back null.